# Как остановить запись логов?

Tags: android-studio, android

Запускаю приложение на смартфоне, оно останавливается, логи скачут как бешеные и пишет что "Too much output pocess". Как остановить это? Я не могу даже посмотреть в чем ошибка чтобы исправить код, все мелькает.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте фильтры логов. В правом углу выбираете Edit Filter Config. в открытом окне заполняете поле Tag вашим значением которое вы указали в Log. Или просто в поиске пропишите значение лога. Пример лога: `Log.v("Value1", value1);`. Фильтровать будете по "Value1".